# Value of x when s = x >> 31 and x = (s & ~x) | (~s & x);

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, 32-bit

If `x` was to equal `12` in a `32` bit scenario, x = multiple 0's into the lsb `0000 1100`. If the above scenario were to run, I believe I would get `0000 1100`. Am I wrong?

Along with that, what if I was to use `x=-1`? Wouldn't `s = 1`, but then does `(s & ~x)` look like `(0001 & 0000)` and `(1110 & 1111)`? Thanks

I thought that `x=-1` would mean `x>>31` would be like `0001` (output `1`), but I don't know if the above is correct.

Comment: Right-shifting a signed (and negative) `int` is implementation-defined

Comment: Although impl defined, on _most_ arches [that are two's complement?], a right shift of a signed value will shift the MSB into the word (from the left). With `x>>31`, this means that the sign bit will be shifted into all the remaining bits. So, with `x = -anything; y = x>>31;` the result `y` is _always_ `-1`

Comment: ^ that is called *sign extension*

Comment: Reminds me of an interview question I got once: *here's some random bit-twiddling x86 assembly. What's it doing?*. The answer was "absolute value". But as harold points out below, this particular set of operations is really  `x = (x >= 0) ? x : -x-1`.  Not quite abs, but close.

Comment: There's no telling what will happen unless you post complete code _including all variable declarations_. This expression will give very different results between signed and unsigned.

Comment: @CraigEstey I've run into some low-end microcontroller compilers that used logical shift instead, either because of some restriction or performance gain, given the ISA.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No it is called arithmetic right shift. Not to be confused with sign extension, for example: `int8_t i8 = -1; printf("%X", i8);` where `i8` gets implicitly promoted to `int`, the sign is preserved, so the resulting hex is 0xFFFFFFFF and not 0xFF. Sign extension is well-defined, unlike right shifting negative numbers, which is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 4):

The typical implementation of a right shift of a signed integer is an [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift). Different implementations are unfortunately still allowed, though rare, and they're not relevant to understanding this code (it ignores such possibilities anyway). Two's complement integers are now mandatory (in C23: "The sign representation defined in this document is called two’s complement. Previous revisions of this document
additionally allowed other sign representation") so I'm not going to do the usual consideration of hypothetical integer representations that haven't been seen since the stone age.

By assumption the number of bits in an `int` is 32, so shifting an `int` right by 31 makes every bit of the result a copy of the sign bit. So if `x` was negative, `s` would be -1.

`x = (s & ~x) | (~s & x)` is a verbose way to spell out `x ^= s`. XORing `x` by 0 leaves it the same as before, XORing it by -1 inverts all the bits. Taking into account that `s = x < 0 ? -1 : 0`, effectively the computation does this:

```
if (x < 0)
    x = ~x;  // equivalent to: x = -x - 1;
```

Comment: I forgot about arithmetic shift! And that makes a lot more sense now, thank you!

Comment: +1 for: _so I'm not going to do the usual consideration of hypothetical integer representations that haven't been seen since the stone age._ ;-)

Comment: However, whether a compiler picks arithmetic right shift or logical right shift when dealing with a negative number has nothing to do with 2's complement as such. Which version that's picked is still implementation-defined in C23. I do recall working with some microcontroller compiler that used logical right shifts, but I have for sure never worked with any CPU that didn't use 2's complement.